# Unexpected call to a function from dynamically loaded library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

During execution of thread sanitizer test, I've noticed something that worries me a little (maybe more from lack of understanding).

The part of the call stack below represents a data race detected by thread sanitizer:

```
Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b4400020080 by thread T4 (mutexes: write M258529629327854840):

#0 malloc <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x2cbe2)
...
#11 std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (MyCustomWorker::*)(), MyCustomWorker*> >::operator()() <null> (myApp+0x11de952)
#12 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (MyCustomWorker::*)(), MyCustomWorker*> > >::_M_run() <null> (myApp+0x11de524)
#13 execute_native_thread_routine <null> (liboatpp.so+0x3e4d3e)
```

The interesting part of this stack is not the data race itself, but the bottom of the call stack:

```
#13 execute_native_thread_routine <null> (liboatpp.so+0x3e4d3e)
```

The oatpp library is used by the binary, but the code where the race happened **is entirely irrelevant to the library**. As I understand it, this line says:

- function `execute_native_thread_routine` of `std::thread` library was called by `liboatpp.so`
- thread that `MyCustomWorker` runs into was created by `liboatpp.so` code

So, for some reason, my binary calls `std::thread` functions through `liboatpp.so`, not as I would expect by itself. What I already (or considered):

1. List of symbols of liboatpp in search of any '*thread*' related symbols that may be looked up during linkage of MyApp. All symbols seems to contain oatpp related names. Result of `nm -gD liboatpp.so | grep thread | grep run`:

```
00000000003c7054 W _ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJMN5oatpp3web6server13HttpProcessor4TaskEFvvES7_EEEEE6_M_runEv
...
(similar oatpp specific entries)
```

2. Search of calls to thread related functions in `liboatpp.so` by executing: `ltrace -l liboatpp.so ./MyApp | grep thread` but nothing interesting is found. I would expect to find some calls responsible for the issue.
3. I've also checked the output of the dynamic linker after exporting `LD_DEBUG=all`, but also nothing interesting is found. Here I would expect to find unresolved symbols in MyApp for thread-related functions to be found in `liboatpp.so`. No such thing observed.

**EDITED:**

libstdc++.a was definitely not intentianaly linked into liboatpp.so. My proof confiriming that it was not linked is that if I take one of following defined symbols in libstdc++.a (`nm -g /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.a | grep thread`):

```
0000000000000000 T _ZNSt6thread20hardware_concurrencyEv
0000000000000000 T _ZNSt6thread4joinEv
0000000000000000 T _ZNSt6thread6detachEv
```

and then search for it in liboattp `nm -gD liboatpp.so | grep thread`:

```
        U _ZNSt6thread6detachEv
```

but it's found as undefined symbol.

Oatpp linking command goes as follows:

```
c++ -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,liboatpp.so -o liboatpp.so CMakeFiles/oatpp.dir/oatpp/algorithm/CRC.cpp.o (...) -lpthread -latomic
```

Comment: I do not not know what liboatpp is, but from the stack trace it seems like this library did create a thread. Why is it so surprising?

Comment: It doesn't seem strange to me. Oat++ is a "web framework" and probably creates threads. That's hardly unexpected. Maybe I'm missing your point? (By the way, the Oat++ website seems to suggest that you should build and link to it as a *static* library: https://oatpp.io/docs/installation/unix-linux/#installation-cmake-options .)

Comment: @yzt Thanks for pointing that out, I'll definitely rebuild Oat++ with proper flags.

Comment: Your "proof" proves _nothing_. `libstdc++.a` consists of many `.o` files, and not all of them may have ended up inside `liboatpp.so`. Showing _how_ you linked `liboatpp.so` might be a good start.

Comment: Also filtering `nm` output to global symbols (the `-g` flag) is counter-productive here.

Answer (score 2):

The `execute_native_thread_routine()` appears to be part of GCC's `libstdc++`.

It's unclear how you linked `liboatpp.so`, but chances are you linked parts of `libstdc++.a` into it.

Assuming that's what happened, there is little surprise that `liboatpp.so`s version of `execute_native_thread_routine()` is getting called as part of any `std::thread` creation -- the linker will use the first definition of this routine available, and that just happens to be in `liboatpp.so`. If you didn't link in `libstdc++.a` into `liboatpp.so`, the linker would have used `libstdc++.so.6`s version instead.